# topology problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

Can anyone tell me how to fix an error after running the topology rule in ArcGIS? I tried to subtract and create a new layer, but a failed warning appears every time.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Because there are so many topology rules you could have set up, it would also be helpful to explain (possibly a graphic), of which topology rule, what type of feature classes participate in the rule, as well as the error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the topology toolbar [image]

[image]

Then use the error inspector to locate the topology error in order to fix the correction

more info
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Editing_features_in_a_topology

Answer (score 2):

If the error you are getting is "Failed to create new feature" and you are using topology in ArcGIS 10, install Service Pack 1 to fix it.

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38133